# How to let the user select which Activity to start when application starts?

Tags: android, android-activity, startup

I want the user to select which Activity the application should start on. I am trying to avoid tabs because I don't like the layout of tabs, but I have a custom title bar that has three icons on which to select functionality/activity.

I want the user to select which activity the application should start from the beginning with a user preferences.

How can I do this?

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After starting the main activity, immediately read from the settings and start the user preferred activity.

Comment: I trying that right now but then when the user press back button after that its comming to that empty activity that was the "real" activity that start from the begining, but its maybe some way to get it to close the application when its gets focu on back?

Comment: Call finish() on the empty activity before firing off the intent that starts up the real activity. I believe you can also use android:noHistory="true" in the manifest for the empty activity to do pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I also offer an alterntaive soultion. This is not an exact answer to your question though, but may help you to solve your problem in an elegant way.

1. Subclass `TabWidget` and define how the row with tabs is drawn.
2. Create a layout file for `TabHost` with your `TabWidget` in it.
3. Subclass TabActivity and set your own layout you've created.
4. Read the saved settings and use `setDefaultTab` method to set the preferred activity.

Voila! You got your own look without losing any functionality of `TabActivity`. You can read [Tab Layout Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for more information on how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks, for another solution but its works great to intent the activity like last answer

Answer (score 1):

What so tough in this. if i have three activity and that i want user to pick one which to start.

### at least one activity has to be served as menu to the user from which user will pick. This will be main activity of app

. i will display three buttons in it and on their specific click i will initiate the respective activity.